# include the page id in a url on my umbraco site

Tags: umbraco

I have a site running on Umbraco 7, that uses the default Url scheme, a url might look like this:

```
http://domain.com/page-name/subpage-name
```

As the content creators likes to "optimize" the pages on the website, they often change the page titles, and in the process change the url of the page, breaking all links linking to the page (google links, ad-words campaigns, partner sites ect.)

I would like to keep the page title in the url, for SEO purposes, and not be stuck with one URL when a page was first created, for this i was thinking of adding the id to the url of the page. I have seen many sites have a url that looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/page/id/subpage-name or http://domain.com/page/id-subpage-name
```

And then lookup the page based on the id instead of the name

Is it possible to achieve this with Umbraco?

Comment: Umbraco appears to be able to treat page URL and page title as separate entities, maybe that's an option if this is not viable

Comment: Yes, that might be the best bet. But i dont really want to go down that route, as the URL and the title of the page will be out of sync which defeats the purpose of having the title in URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with Pekka on this one, it's super easy to create separate field(s) for page header/navigation title/browser title. In my opinion it's a better solution than adding ids to the URL, but that's just my two cents.

You should be able to make a custom URL handler like this: http://24days.in/umbraco/2014/urlprovider-and-contentfinder/ - the article is from 2014, so some stuff may have changed. But the concept should still be relevant.